# graphviz - neato Error generating B-spline edges in 3D?

Tags: graphviz

The following simple graph contains two nodes and one attribute requesting a layout in 3D:

```
graph  g {
graph [ dimen=3];
1--10
}
```

Running neato generates this layout:

```
graph g {
        graph [dimen=3];
        node [label="\N"];
        graph [bb="0,0,121.83,37.8"];
        1 [pos="27,18,-12.036", width="0.75", height="0.5"];
        10 [pos="94.833,19.8,12.036", width="0.75", height="0.5"];
        1 -- 10 [pos="54.199,18.722 58.622,18.839 63.204,18.961 67.627,19.078"];
}
```

Note that the nodes do have 3 coordinates but the controlling points in the edge specification ***have only two***.

Is there something I didn't specify or is this a bug in Graphviz?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [known limitation](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#ddimen) for `dimen` > 2:

> Note that, at present, all aspects of rendering are 2D. This includes
>   the shape and size of nodes, overlap removal, and edge routing. Thus,
>   **for `dimen` > 2, the only valid information is the `pos` attribute of the
>   nodes**. All other coordinates will be 2D and, at best, will reflect a
>   projection of a higher-dimensional point onto the plane.